# HTML and CSS markup for flexible form layout

Tags: html, css, form, layout

I'm trying to have a HTML / CSS structure for flexible layouts for forms. I tried to look at Bootstrap codes for help with this *(without actually using Bootstrap itself)*. I've gone with something along these lines:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/stidyuic

```css
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 30px;}
.form-row {
  display: block;
}
.form-group:first-child {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
form {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0em;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
               <div class="col-6 form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Title</label>
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Test" size="4" type="text">
               </div>
               <div class="col-3 form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                  <select class="form-control">
                     <option value="A">
                        A
                     </option>
                     <option value="B">
                        B
                     </option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <div class="col-3 form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control">
                     <option>
                        A
                     </option>
                     <option>
                        B
                     </option>
                     <option>
                        C
                     </option>
                  </select>
               </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to do the following:

- Have anywhere from 1 to four inputs on each row.
- Have the label above the form
- Modify the form layout with CSS when the resolution changes (media query)

Questions:

- Is it a sensible approach to use this code structure in order to
  achieve this?
- Is taking Bootstrap’s form structure a logical approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks perfectly fine.  In fact, it all validates by the validators at W3C perfectly fine, with one exception - your HTML file should be structured like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Your Page Title Here</title>
        <!-- other code here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- your display code here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The validators can be found here:

> [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)
>   [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)

Your code seems perfectly fine the way it is, and I would say the only thing wrong with it is from the user's perspective.  You have the Category menu overlapping the Title menu, which is not good; you should adjust your columns to prevent this.

Comment: May I ask what browser you are using when you say the category menu is overlapping as I don't see that on my end

Comment: @Jimmy No problem.  I am using IceDragon, which is based on FireFox but is more secure and has a different UI.  I just tested in on IE, and it looks great there.

Comment: IceDragon: http://i.imgur.com/b6l5rKv.png

Comment: IE: http://i.imgur.com/6hwiZxH.png